# El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección. ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

tengo el siguiente evento `RowUpdating` de un `GridView` y cuando le doy click al 'Actualizar' me arroja el siguiente error :

> El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e
>   inferior al tamaño de la colección. Nombre del parámetro: index

El error es en la siguiente linea : `GridViewRow fila = GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];`

Cabe Recalcar cuando ejecuto el codigo linea por linea la parte de **e.RowIndex** obtiene un valor de 9 , pero la siguiente parte de '**GridView2.Rows**' no obtiene el valor 9 y se queda como null o 0

Adjunto código fuente del programa:

**C#**

```
 protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {


            GridViewRow fila;
            fila = GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            string IdUsuPerfil = GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
            DropDownList NombreCargoDL = (DropDownList)fila.FindControl("comboBox2");
            string NombreCargo = NombreCargoDL.SelectedValue;
            int ejecutar = 0;
            ejecutar = wsObj.sp_UpdateCargoSn(Convert.ToString(NombreCargo), IdUsuPerfil);

            GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
            LlenarGV();


        }
```

**HTML**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"  DataKeyNames="Username"  CellPadding="4" EnableViewState="false" style="width:1130px"
                ForeColor="#333333"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                OnRowEditing="GridView2_RowEditing"
                OnRowUpdating="GridView2_RowUpdating" 
                OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView2_RowCancelingEdit" 
                OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound"

                >

                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="IdUsuPerfil" HeaderText="IdUsuPerfil" ReadOnly="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" ReadOnly="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Nombres" HeaderText="Nombres" ReadOnly="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="IdCargo" HeaderText="IdCargo"  ReadOnly="True"/> 

                            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="NombreCargo">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="comboBox2" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"  CssClass="Textboxingreso" ></asp:DropDownList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="LblNomPerfil" runat="server" Text='<% # Bind("NombreCargo") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="20%" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Activo" HeaderText="Activo" ReadOnly="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Origen" HeaderText="Origen"  ReadOnly="True"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="IdAplicativo" HeaderText="IdAplicativo"  ReadOnly="True" />
                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="link" HeaderText="Modificar" CausesValidation="false" ShowEditButton="True" ShowCancelButton="true" />


                </Columns>


                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#FFD800" />             
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#3E4043" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFD800" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3E4043" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFD800" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#FFD800" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Agrega un punto de interrupcion y revisa cuantas celdas tienes para cada renglon GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells

Comment: Me lanza el siguiente error  [ Mi código está asi  : fila = GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells; ]
: 

Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido Estado suprimido
Error CS0029 No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCellCollection' en 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'

Comment: Y si pongo el código asi : GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells;
Me lanza el siguiente error :
Solo las expresiones de asignación, llamada, incremento, decremento, espera y objeto nuevo se pueden usar como instrucción WebApplication1

Comment: Lo puse de tal forma `_ = GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells; ` y cuenta 9 celdas

Comment: intenta Gridvew2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString(); para obtener el valor

Comment: Si me pudieras insertar o decirme en que lugar poner o reemplazar el código dentro del mío te lo agradecería por favor

Comment: si gustas ponlo al principio en teoria te debe entregar el valor del primer elemento del renglon seleccionado   string IdUsuPerfil=Gridvew2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();

Comment: una duda, en que evento cargas los datos del grid? o sea en que otro evento invocas al LlenarGV() ademas del RowUpdating